# How to extend java classes on in Python with JPype as its interfacing mechanism with java?

Tags: jpype

I use JPype to build a SOAP client in my *python based test platform*. However, I need to extend a Java class to make a call like this:

Like

> void process(Context parameter)

The type *Context* here is a class and to give an implementation, I need to extend *Context* in python using JPype.

> class MyContext extends Context { //override the methods}

With JProxy functionality (in JPype), I'm able to "implement" java interfaces.

But I want to extend a class not an interface. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very much a limitation. JPype does not allow sub-classing.

[sourceforge link](https://sourceforge.net/p/jpype/mailman/message/18756209/)

Changed the SOAP method to accept an interface in the API contract.

Answer (score -1):

**JPype is an effort to allow Python programs full access to Java class libraries. This is achieved not through re-implementing Python, as Jython/JPython has done, but rather through interfacing at the native level in both virtual machines.
Eventually, it should be possible to replace Java with Python in many, though not all, situations. JSP, Servlets, RMI servers and IDE plugins are all good candidates.
Once this integration is achieved, a second phase will be started to separate the Java logic from the Python logic, eventually allowing the bridging technology to be used in other environments, i.e. Ruby, Perl, COM, etc ..**